# Create an Associative array in PHP

Tags: php

How do I write PHP code to manually create this array?

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array 
    ( 
        [Id] => 2 
        [Fruit] => Apple 
    ) 
[1] => Array 
    ( 
        [Id] => 5 
        [Fruit] => Orange
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Learn about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = array("Id" => 2, "Fruit" => "Apple");
$arr[] = array("Id" => 5, "Fruit" => "Orange");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array =array(
                array('Id'=>2, 'Fruit'=>'Apple'),
                array('Id'=>5, 'Fruit'=>'Orange')                     
              );
```

**NB:** array keys are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
$array[] = array(
    'id'=>3,
    'Fruit'=>'Orange'
);
$array[] = array(
    'id'=>7,
    'Fruit'=>'Banana'
);
```